# RoR 3 Aproval on records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, blogs

I have an blog where anyone can comment. I would like to approve the comments before they are published. I have a boolean field named "published" and I'm unsure what to do next. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine several features :

- you need to be be notified when a comment is created. If you're not expecting too much traffic, the application can notify you by email with the [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
- you need an admin page where you'll see all the comments that are waiting from your approval. Use [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to ensure that only you have access to this page.
- you'll certainly need to see the comments "in situ" before approving them. The blog page should display only "published" comments for average user, but for you it should display all comments, with a button to publish the ones waiting for approval.

Comment: Thanks Baldrick, please can you give me an example of how to code point 3?